# Web Navigation Menu types & general implementation Patterns

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Are there well known `Navigation Menu patterns` for implementing dynamic navigation menus with `drop down panels` on a **Website**?

*For example*, clicking the **`StackExchange`** link in the top left displays a div with content and your **`Username`** displays a similar panel but uses a different event to display the content.

Do these types of menus and others have formal pattern names which quality examples can be found & are there any `Nuget` packages that provide implementations in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

No... These are customized menus that have many jquery or javascript codes behind themselves...

Maybe the simplest way for you, is that find and open source menu plugin and tweak it with jquery. You can find many intresting jquery menu plugins. Just google it...